# To pour liquid medicine into a Teaspoon/ Tablespoon (for exact measure) from a dark glass/ plastic bottle without wastage, spillage or dripping?

Tags: home, kitchen, medicine, liquids

To pour liquid medicine into a Teaspoon/ Tablespoon (for exact measure) from a dark glass/ plastic bottle without wastage, spillage or dripping?

Found these similar ones, but they are bigger containers and do not require the subtler smaller movements and tact that are inapplicable here. Also unable to transfer their inputs into the required spoon while having only 2 hands.

[How do I pour from a mug without having it drip so much?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/252/how-do-i-pour-from-a-mug-without-having-it-drip-so-much)

https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/85802/how-to-prevent-liquids-from-spilling-when-pouring-from-measuring-cup

https://lifehacker.com/avoid-spills-when-pouring-liquids-with-a-chopstick-5879358

Is there some technique or hack I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

Obtain a paired bung-and-syringe:

[image]

- Uncap the bottle
- Insert the stepped bung into the bottle opening
- Insert the syringe into the plastic bung
- Invert the whole thing and hold the body of the syringe in one hand and the plunger of the syringe in the other (so it's like a lollipop, with the syringe being the stick)

  - If the bung is not a great fit, consider holding the syringe body with your middle, ring and little finger and use your pointing finger and thumb to hold the bottle
  - Over time the synringe may go stiff, and is more at risk of being pulled out of the bung while the bottle is inverted. Ensure the focus of your grip is on the syringe body or replace the syringe
- Draw the medicine of the required amount into the plunger
- Grip the bottle again and turn it back the right way up
- Detach the syringe and use it to feed the medicine to the recipient

The entire process is far less messy and spill prone than other methods.

Some liquid medicines (particularly those intended for children) have a dedicated plastic bung inserted in the neck of the bottle, and come with a crude syringe that exactly fits the hole in the bung. The plastic bung can be removed from the bottle and transferred to another bottle. If it doesn't fit, then the medicine from the other bottle can be transferred to this bottle, but it's then absolutely paramount importance that the bottle is labelled correctly so that the label reflects the contents. **Do not rely on putting a wrongly labelled bottle in a correctly labelled box**; completely remove or deface the original label and apply a new label with the correct dosage instructions to the bottle like a pharmacy would

Answer (score 2):

You might not even need a spoon! you can use a special spoon, or you can recycle the medical cap from the liquid medicine, those little caps that come with mililiter indicators, you can even buy a whole bag o them at low cost! they are very usefull, as they have those walls and they indicate the amount of liquid as I said before.
check the [google site](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fes.dhgate.com%2Fproduct%2F20ml-travel-cup-of-liquid-pe-liquid-case%2F402513334.html&psig=AOvVaw3ah4CcLmXGbB0ZRXjlj5tZ&ust=1586863126969000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKDswP2j5egCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD), it doesn't just show you an image of one, but it also tells you the price, the amount you want to buy, etc.:

Comment: It's not as much as to be called a hack but it can still be called a technique, I would like some comments on my advice/answer!

Comment: You seem to use a lot of words that do not help, hiding the actual answer.  (And please do not use your last line: I hope etc. as all who answer here hope that.)

Comment: @MKNick10 I took the liberty to shorten your answer. If you disagree with my edit, you can revert it back to the original content by clicking on "edited X ago by Elmy" (below the answer) and then clicking on "rollback" on the entry you want.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a tea/tablespoon. They are not exact, and require a very steady hand to avoid spilling because they have to be filled to the brim.

Instead, use the tools intended for the purpose: a medicine cup or spoon. These are graduated, so you can see exactly how much you have, and they are large enough that you can fill them to the "1 tablespoon" level and still be below the rim.

To pour without spilling:

[image]

1. place the neck of the bottle on the rim of the cup. This will stabilize them both. And you're certain that all liquid from the bottle will end up in the cup, and not run down the side of the bottle.
2. Tip the bottle slowly.